# package.json dependencies wont work on my local windows host but it works in docker Why?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, yarnpkg

I have downloaded the sample docker getting-started project from: [getting-started-webpage](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/)

```
{
    "name": "101-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "prettify": "prettier -l --write \"**/*.js\"",
        "test": "jest",
        "dev": "nodemon src/index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mysql": "^2.17.1",
        "sqlite3": "^4.1.0",
        "uuid": "^3.3.3",
        "wait-port": "^0.2.2"
    },
    "prettier": {
        "trailingComma": "all",
        "tabWidth": 4,
        "useTabs": false,
        "semi": true,
        "singleQuote": true
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
        "prettier": "^1.18.2"
    }
}
```

Exception thrown::

```
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ulrich Giorgio Jäger\IdeaProjects\docker-tutorial-app\node_modules\sql
ite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js:4:15)
error MODULE_NOT_FOUND
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

So my question is why it works when copied to  docker container and not locally

i could update all the dependecies from settings.json now this error is gone.
I struggle now with another problem

```
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" run dev --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

> 101-app@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Ulrich Giorgio Jäger\IdeaProjects\docker-tutorial-app
> nodemon src/index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
Using sqlite database at /etc/todos/todo.db
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:6942
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1320:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1368:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1505:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1347:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6942
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting.
```

has anybody have an idea on why. this is not working on my local machine after so many updates still the port is being marked as occupied even if its open for new connections

Comment: What command are you executing to run your project? Have you executed `npm install` to install dependencies before starting you project? How does the dockerfile look like?

Comment: yes sure i did yarn & npm install all gone through but running it with dev script it throws an [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Also asked on https://forums.docker.com/t/package-json-works-in-docker-but-not-locally-why/113267

Comment: hi @Arjan any suggestions on why i cannot run it locally?